# Can Repaint be tested?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there currently an API that effectively resolves the following pseudo code?

```
var myElement = document.querySelector("#foo");

if (myElement[mustBeRepainted]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

That is, the idea of a "dirty" element, or an element which on the next repaint must be repainted or different from its current on-screen state.

I'm not too picky about how it's implemented, although I'm hoping for something like `myElement.isDirty` or `paintQueue("myElement")`.

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Comment: How would you come to know whether an element is "dirty" and must be repainted?

Comment: Plalx, the project goal is to have a module that supports the following attribute:

  var watcher = new Watcher()
   , listener = new Listener();
  watcher.watch(myElement).attribute("height").is("420px");  
  watcher.tell(listener);

  listener.hear(watcher, function(msg) {
   if(msg = "myElement.height.is.420px") { myElement.addClass([some class]) }
}
}


the idea being that it is fairly heavy to test this on every frame, and if a lighter "has changed" flag exists, then that would make testing more efficient.

Comment: Aadit,  that's exactly the question I'm asking... is there a way to know.

I.e.  Is there an attribute, or an API that we can test against.  I'm not sure how rephrasing the question is helpful?

Comment: @CrispenSmith: That’s going to be heavy either way. Why do you need that module? (Hint: you probably don’t)

Comment: Oh, I know it's going to be heavy, which is why I really don't want to write it.


I'm putting together a new class-centric animation runner, the main engine is just a scheduler to add and remove classes, in essence being agnostic of how those classes change the state of the elements of the page.  I'd *like* to include this test so  that we can have elements respond to other elements changing.   This is NOT for serious "mission critical" product, more like abstract graphic art w. music sort of contexts.  I appreciate how painfully heavy it is likely to be.

Comment: I mean, honestly... if I *could* make it light enough I could see times when making a browser-agnostic mutation observer could be useful in business contexts, but I think that's a pipe-dream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to catch an attribute change rather than an actual operating system's paint message (e.g. [WM_PAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), you could simply [observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) the wanted dom element:

```
function trackDomChanges(I_oHTMLObject) {
    //create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(
        function(mutations) {
            mutations.forEach(
                function(mutation) { 
                    // play with mutation.attributeName, oldValue etc.
                }
            );
        }
    );
    observer.observe(I_oHTMLObject, { attributes: true, childList: false, characterData: false });
}

trackDomChanges(myElement);
```

Comment: That's a really good solution for newer browsers and I intend to implement it.  But for safety we have to test for the existence of the MutationObserver object (currently I think it's webkit only though I may be mistaken).  What I'm trying to find is a good (or reasonably good) solution to older browsers... which in this case is a large section of the ecosystem.  I was hoping that browsers might expose this information in a way that I simply hadn't thought of.  I'm beginning to feel the answer to this question is some formal version of "no"  and that's a perfectly fine answer in this case.

Comment: Do you know anyway that even though you get a `mutation`, it does not mean that the object has to be repainted, it means the object actually already changed and has been repainted.

Comment: +1 for mutation observer have not heard of it before now, did some research and it is awesome

Comment: Yes, I agree.

The only value in finding an exposed repaint indicator (attribute or function response) is that it may have been an older more stable (if arcane) way to tell the module to send the message in older browsers.  Sequence is really not critical at 60fps as long as a response is triggered when a statement becomes true and that statement can be made as an api call to the observer.  With mutation observers we can pass the statement to a wrapper, sae approach would work with a repaint test.  But, it's not going to break the project not to have it.  It *may* have offered a per gain.